# How to set limit paging of Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

In PHP+MySQL, I'm paging my lists by :

`SELECT...FROM...LIMIT {($page - 1) * $perPage}, {$perPage}`

But in Mongodb, `limit` aggregation only assign `perPage`
Example

```
db.article.aggregate(
    { $limit : 5 }
);
```

How can I write query in MongoDB like MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can use skip , it can be used as a offset.

```
db.article.aggregate(
    { $limit : 5 },
    { $skip : 50 }
);
```

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/skip/